# Pros & cons of configuring logging at server-level vs application-level

Tags: java, logging

Configuring logging in java can sometimes be tricky (due to the multiple existing logging APIs) and can be done at different levels (server, application, both?). So what are the pros and cons to configure logging at those levels?

I came with this list but I would like others to share their experience:

- Server-level

  - Pros

    - Centralized configuration
    - Application must not be modified prior to deployment
    - Can log to resources managed by the server (files relative to server path, DB...)
  - Cons

    - Must be sure each application uses the same logging api
    - Configuration can grow big as more applications are deployed
    - Server knows maybe too much about categories=>logging-level mapping for each application
- Application-level

  - Pros

    - Application may use the logging api of its choice
    - Application can configure its own logging-levels
  - Cons

    - Configuration must be edited prior to deployment in order to specify path to logfiles (if relative to server) or JNDI name of the logdatabase

Is there a way to combine the two to keep only pros? Like configuring loggers at the server-level and then categories=>logging-level mapping at the application-level?

Comment: in our case, we handle logging as an interface - basically, developers define what is logged and on what channels, and then the configuration is done per-server.

the main issue here is that we NEVER deploy anything that would be environment-specific together with the application. like this, DEV and QA environments can set certain channels to debug, while LIVE environments do not. i found this to be a very doable. 

what makes your logging configuration so complicated?

Comment: I'm having a bit of time on my hands and I like when I can drop my application archive straight to my deployment folder without any modification **at all** (configuration of external resources should happen at server-side). It's easy for databases, jms queues, mail sessions and I did it for ehcache managers too (because sometimes it needs to persist data to disk which is external to the application). Now I'm trying to do the same for logging... but I admit it's a bit different and harder because the server needs logging too as soon as it starts (while it doesn't need DB, queues...).

Answer (score 0):

> Is there a way to combine the two to keep only pros? Like configuring loggers at the server-level and then categories=>logging-level mapping at the application-level?

- To answer this question I would say, Yes, we can do. But in this case your server and applications have to follow a proper design and in the negative side all the application might become tightly coupled.

If your apps are java based then, you can actually make a single logger file for all applications and there you have to set the application logger level, provided your applications follow different package structures.

Suppose app1 follows package structure com.app1.*.* and app2 follow com.app2.*.*, then you can modify logger level like below,

```
*.*.com.app1 = logger_level1
*.*.com.app2 = logger_level2
```

But if your app2 is dependent on app1, or it has package like this com.app1.app2.* or some common package names, then you might have define more on the logger properties, so the package structure and design is very much important to follow single logging mechanism.